# Unable to dock Main Menu in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arccatalog

For some reason the Main Menu dis-attached itself from the ArcCatalog window and I am not able to dock it or even move it when i click the menu title bar. The functions work but it's just stuck in place on screen and I can't do anything with it.  The title bar itself appears dimmed.

[image]

Comment: delete or rename normal.mxt to 'normal_old.mxt' will create a new one an it should be back in the default location.

Comment: If it is dimmed then what I am about to suggest will probably not work but it is always something else to try.  A double-click on the title bar of a floating toolbar (or window) should return it to the position at which it was last docked.

Comment: Thanks guys. Didn't think the mxt rebuilt would work since this is ArcCatalog but i will try that. @PolyGeo - tried everything i could think of with the mouse to to move it including double clicking numerous times. It's pretty much dead stuck there. The strange thing is that even though its dimmed the dro-downs still work including all functions.

Comment: There is a Normal.gxt for ArcCatalog equivalent to the Normal.mxt for ArcMap.

Comment: Perfect, not I now there is an arcCatalog template! @PolyGeo - please make that an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Renaming the Normal.gxt to Old.gxt and restarting ArcCatalog did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: old bug...still happening on 10.4.1. Did they get around to fixing it in later versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your symptoms suggest that returning ArcCatalog to its factory settings may be worth considering.  To reset ArcCatalog you can delete or rename your Normal.gxt (in a similar fashion to how you may reset ArcMap via its Normal.mxt).

The Online Help page entitled [About configuring the user interface](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00v000000014000000) describes where to find these templates:

> The Normal templates—Normal.mxt (ArcMap), Normal.gxt (ArcCatalog),
>   Normal.3dt (ArcGlobe), and Normal.sxt (ArcScene)—are located in your
>   user settings folder. For example, in Windows 2000 or XP, the ArcMap
>   Normal.mxt can be found in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\\Application Data\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap\Templates,
>   and in Windows Vista, it can be found in
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap\Templates.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting the normal.gxt file worked for me. Only problem is that with our locked down SOE (Win 7)(state government) the file was in the  "\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog" folder (the \Application Data folder is locked down). Eventually found the right file by doing a global search on C:.